# Regarding New Admob POLICY

Tags: android, google-play, admob

https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en
Admob updated new photos regarding interstitial implementations. For fixing violation. İt states that user clicks app on home page ---> app loading---> interstitial ad-----> home screen of app is a proper way of implementation of the interstitial ad. is this true if i implement interstitial ads in this way ? Ex: user clicks app on home page ----> splash screen loading ----> home screen of the app loaded and then show the interstitial ads ? Thank you for info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You should show ad in between activities. For example you can do this:

**Scenario 1**

1. User clicks app on home page
2. Splash screen loading
3. As soon as splash screen loading ends and you are about to move to shome screen, show interstitial ad
4. If user closes ad then he should land on Home screen (not splash screen)
5. On ad closed by user; Home screen of the app loads

[image]

**Scenario 2**

1. User clicks app on home page
2. Splash screen loading
3. Home screen of the app loaded
4. User clicks some button (or on any action); go to activity B
5. Now show interstitial ad before going to Activity B
6. If user closes ad then he should land on Activity B (Home screen)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you're trying to fix the problem of displaying Interstitials upon App exit or start.

As a general rule an interstitial ad shouldn't be the first or last thing the user sees. Upon startup, don't show an ad before an activity is shown. And when the user exit, don't show an ad forcing him to close it in order to leave your app.

Comment: Hımm Thank you for replying. Then this way of integrating ads; user clicks app on home page ----> splash screen loading ----> home screen of the app loaded and then show the interstitial ads after ads loaded would be proper ways according to policy of admob.

Comment: The policy is that Interstitials should be displayed between activities, and not on startup or exit. The first or last thing the user sees should not be an interstitial ad.